# Finding element in array within a document

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB/Mongoose, I'm trying to find all documents that their `usersInvited` array contains a certain `UID`.

Example:
a search through this collection with `UID=123` should return `id1`, `id2`

```
[
  {
    "_id": "id1",
    "usersInvited": [
      {
        "UID": "123"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "id2",
    "usersInvited": [
      {
        "UID": "123"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "id3",
    "usersInvited": [
      {
        "UID": "abc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch` for this:

```
db.myCollection.find({
  usersInvited: {
    $elemMatch: {
      UID: "123"
    }
  }
})
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-an-array-of-documents

Answer (score 2):

You can directly query against the `UID` field within the `usersInvited` array elements using dot notation:

```
MyModel.find({'usersInvited.UID': '123'}, (err, docs) => {...});
```

If any of the elements of the array has a `UID` value of `'123'`, the document will be included.

Comment: @bubakazouba: You'd replace `'123'` with `{ '$oid': '123' }`, though I don't use Mongo and just read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = FriendHittups.find({
  usersInvited: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "UID": "123"
    }
  }
});

query.exec(function (err, results){

});
```